# How do I dynamically change margin depending on an absolutely positioned elements height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to dynamically change the margin-top of an element depending on the height of another absolutely positioned image.

Before anyone asks, it has to be absolutely positioned because of other reasons so I can't just make it relative.

I am able to change the margin only when I type in an absolute value such as "200px". However, when I try to use a variable to dynamacally change the margin-top on every window rezise, it simply don't give the element any margin at all.

Any help would be helpful.
Thank you in advance!

```
var element;
var textIntro;
var newMargin;

function setMargin() {
    element = document.getElementById("cover1");
    newMargin = element.style.height;
    document.getElementById("TextIntro").style.marginTop = newMargin;
}
```

Comment: So the margin you try to add, is equal to the height of the other  absolute element ?

Comment: You are correct

Comment: Did you try to replace the `.style.marginTop` by `.style.top` as the position absolute is based on the top ? Is the parent relative ?

Comment: Is your problem solved ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you this Js:

```js
setMargin();

function setMargin() {
    element = document.getElementById("cover");
    newMargin = element.offsetHeight;
    document.getElementById("cover1").style.top = newMargin +"px";
}
```

### DEMO

```js
var element;
var textIntro;
var newMargin;

setMargin();

function setMargin() {
    element = document.getElementById("cover");
    newMargin = element.offsetHeight;
    document.getElementById("cover1").style.top = newMargin +"px";
}
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
body > div {
  position:relative;
  padding:20px;
  height:500px;
  width: 90vw;
  background-color:red;
}
body > div > div {
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  width:calc(100% - 80px); /* Padding parent + this object */
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}
body > div > #cover{
  background-color:green;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
}
body > div > #cover1{
  background-color:blue;
  height:200px;
}
body > div > #cover2{
  background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="cover"></div>
  <div id="cover1"></div>
</div>
```